# How extract individual values from POST request in Django Model Form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Would like to be able to access data in a post request directly as well as processing it in the normal way. First created form:

```py
class TransactionForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Transaction
       fields = ['dish', 'customer', 'grams', 'amount_payable']
```

('customer' is the pk of another model, Customer.)
Then process form:

```py
@csrf_exempt 
def create_transaction(request):
    print(request.POST)
    user_input = TransactionForm(request.POST)
    print (user_input)
    if user_input.is_valid():
        user_input.save()

        #customerobject = Customer.objects.get(pk= PK-TAKEN FROM POST)
        #customerobject.account_balance -= (amount_payable TAKEN FROM POST)
        #customerobject.save()

        return HttpResponse('AOK~')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(user_input) #'ERROR: transaction not valid~')
```

Am struggling to correctly formulate the commented lines above. (The rest works fine.)
Would like to be able to extract the value 'customer' from the POST in order to find the customer. Then to extract the value 'amount_payable' from the POST in order to deduct it from the customer's balance.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually stumbled upon the relevant command:

```py
        cust = user_input.cleaned_data.get('customer')
        customerobject = Customer.objects.get(pk=cust.id)
        customerobject.account_balance -= user_input.cleaned_data.get('amount_payable')
        customerobject.save()
```

Low-level languages are easier for sieve-heads like me.